# wso2is-4.6.0 on JBoss 5.x

Tags: wso2

I have the wso2is-4.6.0
Followed instruction for Carbon 4.x and above installation on JBoss 5.x

> http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/03/running-wso2-carbon310-based-products-jboss-5x/

When I start Jboss, it comes up fine.

```
2014-05-29 00:41:03,735 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/wso2
2014-05-29 00:41:03,773 INFO  [STDOUT] (main) OSGi console has been enabled with options: -console 19444
2014-05-29 00:41:04,043 INFO  [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (main) Loading profile: ProfileKey@14f7a86[domain=default, server=default, name=wso2idp]
2014-05-29 00:41:04,051 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.144.11-8080
2014-05-29 00:41:04,063 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (main) Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-192.168.144.11-8009
2014-05-29 00:41:04,069 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.144.11-8443
2014-05-29 00:41:04,074 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)] Started in 13s:159ms
```

But when I access `https://192.168.144.11:8443/wso2/carbon`

I am getting this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - BridgeServlet: /wso2/carbon
```

type Status report

```
message BridgeServlet: /wso2/carbon
```

description The requested resource (`BridgeServlet: /wso2/carbon) is not available`.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 no longer supports deploying Carbon products in other containers starting from Carbon 4.0.0. WSO2 Carbon products comes with Tomcat which is used as the server container.